# Linear search in x64 assembly did not return the right index

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, linear-search

I'm trying to write a linear search subroutine in x64 assembly that return the index of the target
It takes four parameter. This function will scan through an array iteratively until it finds the target element or reaches the end of the array. The function takes in three parameters. The first parameter is a pointer to an int array. The second parameter is an integer representing the size of the array. The third parameter is an integer representing the target element to find in the array. The return type of this fuction is int, and will be the index into the array that the target was found, or -1 if it wasn’t

I wrote a psudeocode for this

```
int linearSearch(int * arr, int size, int target){
    int a;
    int index = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(arr[i] == target){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

And here is my code for that

```
    global linearSearch
    
linearSearch:
    ;the prologue
    xor rax, rax    ;zero out the return address
    xor r10, r10    ;zero out the counter
    
linearSearchIterative:
    ;function body
    mov rax, -1     ;int index = -1 if not found
    cmp r10, rsi    ;compare counter i with the size
    je done         ;done with the program
    cmp rdx, [rdi+4*r10]    ;compare target with arr[i]
    je linearSearchAlter    ;jump to the index fixing part if arr[i] == target
    inc r10         ;i++
    jmp linearSearchIterative   ;go back to the start of the loop
    
linearSearchAlter:
    ;This part change the return index to where the target is
    mov rax, r10    ;index = i
    jmp done    ;end the loop
    
    
done:
    ret
```

However, the subroutine is only returning -1, which is not expected.
I'm using a testing cpp file to test my code which should give the folliowing expected result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

extern "C" int linearSearch(int * arr, int size, int target);

int main(){

    int size;
    // prompt for array size
    cout << "Enter the array size: ";
    cin >> size;
    int * arr = new int[size];

    // read in array values
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "Enter value " << i << ": ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    int target;
    // prompt for target
    cout << "Enter target to search for: ";
    cin >> target;

    int ind = linearSearch(arr, size, target);
    cout << ind << endl;

    if (ind > -1)
        cout << "\nFound " << target << " at index " << ind << endl;
    else
        cout << "\nDid not find " << target << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The expected result should be (I add a print statement to check the value of the index)

```
Enter the array size: 5
Enter value 0: -7
Enter value 1: 2
Enter value 2: -39
Enter value 3: 12
Enter value 4: 8
Enter target to search for: 2
1

Found 2 at index 1
```

Instead, my result is (I add a print statement to check the value of the index)

```
Enter the array size: 5
Enter value 0: -7
Enter value 1: 2
Enter value 2: -39
Enter value 3: 12
Enter value 4: 8
Enter target to search for: 2
-1

Did not find 2
```

So it seems that the subroutine always return -1 instead of the index of the target. Where should the problem be? Thanks

Comment: Or better replace `r10` with `rax` and then you can additionally remove `xor r10, r10` and `mov rax, r10` lines, and remove at least one `jmp`.

Comment: I tried to change it to cmp rdx, [rdi+4*r10] and it doesn't help, the problem is still there TAT

Comment: `cmp rdx, [rdi+4*r10]` is a qword compare, but you're passing it an `int *`.  int elements are only 32 bits wide.  That's at least 1 problem, there are probably others.  e.g. you start by zeroing RAX, but then you `mov rax, -1` so the initial zeroing was totally useless.

Comment: But for the cmp what should I use instead? How should I fix this one?

Comment: `cmp edx, [rdi+4*r10]` ?